# Axiom of countable choice and injective functions

Tags: axiom-of-choice

The axiom of countable choice states that for every countable collection $\{S_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of non empty sets there is a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} S_n$ such that $f(n) \in S_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

For every set $X$ I can apply the axiom of countable choice to prove that there exists a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to X$ simply considering the case in which $S_n = X$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, if $X$ is an infinite set, how can I use the axiom of countable choice to prove that there exists an injective function $f : \mathbb{N} \to X$?

Comment: Of course, you don't need to use any sort of choice to prove there is $f\colon\Bbb N\to X$, assuming $X$ is non-empty.